# how to change .htaccess of zend framework

Tags: .htaccess

I want my first url should be unique

1) `https://abc.com/index`
2) `https://abc.com/index/`
3) `https://www.abc.com/`
4) `https://www.abc.com/index`

i want if some one type above url then user will redirect to `https://abc.com/`
Please help me I am new to zend framework 
my .htaccess code is here

Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index(\.php)?[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301,NC,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ – [L]

RewriteRule ^ /index.php [L]
```

Please help me to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

Put this rule as your first rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+index(\.php)?/?[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^index(\.php)?/?$ https://abc.com/ [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ – [L]

RewriteRule ^ /index.php [L]
```

Comment: thanks i want if some type url in upper case after my website url then it will be redirected to lower case

Comment: That is totally separate problem so request you to create a new question for that and accept this answer.

Comment: I want if some one type http://aerofleet.ca/index.php then it will be redirected to http://aerofleet.ca                 #Options +FollowSymLinks
#Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
Redirect 301 /index https://aerofleet.ca/
#RewriteRule ^https://aerofleet.ca/$ /index.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ http://aerofleet.ca/ [R=301,L]
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ – [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php [NC,L]

Comment: It is impossible to read the code from your comment. Can you edit your question and provide this code.

Comment: i add your lines for redirecting the url which you post yesterday i have one more request please i want also if someone type https://abc.com/index.php then it will be redirected to main url only for index

Comment: Sure that is possible with the rule I suggested. Just make sure to place it before your other rules.

Comment: #Options +FollowSymLinks
#Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
#Redirect 301 /index https://aerofleet.ca/
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index(\.php)?[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.php$ $1 [L,R=301,NC,NE]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ http://aerofleet.ca/ [R=301,L]
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ – [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php [NC,L]

Comment: You are still not using my suggested rule. Just place this rule before you code in question.

Comment: actually i place am using zend framework if am placing your rewrite rule then all other pages not working

Comment: Not working because of your existing rules. If you follow my suggestions I'd would definitely work.

Comment: RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index(\.php)?[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.php$ $1 [L,R=301,NC,NE]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
#RewriteRule ^.*$ – [NC,L]

#RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php [NC,L]

Comment: if am using your rule then it shows https://aerofleet.ca/home/users/web/b1817/nf.aerofleet/public_html/aerofleet/public/ because am using zend framework

Comment: I updated my answer to show your full .htaccess whih should work fine for you.

Comment: Dear its not working i just copy and paste your codeon my page its shows 500 internal server error Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index(\.php)?[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301,NC,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ – [L]

RewriteRule ^ /index.php [L]

Comment: Can you check your Apache error.log and see what the error is for 500?

Comment: there is no data related .htacess

Comment: hey anubhava now its working i just change the sequence of some rules can you please add one more rule for me please its a request if someone type http://sim.ca/index.php/ also this will be redirected to http://sim.ca thanks in advance

Comment: Ok can you post your latest code in your question then I can sure enhance it.

Comment: Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index(\.php)?[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301,NC,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ – [L]

RewriteRule ^ /index.php [L]

Comment: No not in comment but in question since no one can read it in comments.

Comment: i updated my question please check there is a latest .htacess

Comment: its not working all the things are okay but only "index.php/" this is not working